# Crystal Report: How can i merge and split rows in details section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

Hi i am new to stack overflow, and I am having a problem in crystal report.

Thank you in advance

I am getting output from database like

```
Name                   Qty    Rate   Amount

Mango ice cream        1       100    100

Chocobar               1       150    150

Zulubar                1       50      50

Chocolate cone         1       50      50

Kulfi                  1       100    100 

ABC                    1       100    100

XYZ                    1       50      50

Total:-                               600
```

Now what I want to do is merge first three raw and split on 3rd raw.
I want the output to look like this

```
Name                                      Amount

Mango ice creame, Chocobar, Zulubar       300

Chocolate cone, Kulfi, ABC                250

XYZ                                       50 

Total:-                                   600
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you include what you have tried so far and be more specific about any errors you might have gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your requirement is static and no dynamic is involved. Follow below process:

1. Create 3 detail sections, `detailA`, `detail B` and `detail C`
2. Create a formula `@First` place it in detail A.

   ```
   Local Numbervar var_Mango_ice_creame;
   Local Numbervar var_Chocobar;
   Local Numbervar var_Zulubar;
   Shared Numbervar total;

   if Name='Mango ice creame'
   then var_Mango_ice_creame:= Amount;

   if Name='Chocobar'
   then var_Chocobar:= Amount;

   if Name='Zulubar'
   then var_Zulubar:= Amount;

   total:=total+var_Mango_ice_creame+var_Chocobar+var_Zulubar;
   var_Mango_ice_creame+var_Chocobar+var_Zulubar;
   ```
3. Similarly create 2nd formula `@second` place it in `Detail2`

   ```
   Local Numbervar var_Chocolate cone;
   Local Numbervar var_Kulfi;
   Local Numbervar var_ABC;
   Shared Numbervar total;

   if Name='Chocolate cone'
   then var_Chocolate cone:= Amount;

   if Name='Kulfi'
   then var_Kulfi:= Amount;

   if Name='ABC'
   then var_ABC:= Amount;

   total:=total+var_Chocolate cone+var_Kulfi+var_ABC;
   var_Chocolate cone+var_Kulfi+var_ABC;
   ```
4. Create 3rd formula `@Third` place it in Detail C

   ```
   Local Numbervar var_XYZ;
   Shared Numbervar total;

   if Name='XYZ'
   then var_XYZ:= Amount;

   total:=total+var_XYZ;
   var_XYZ;
   ```
5. Create 4th formula `Display` and place in report footer.

   ```
    Shared Numbervar total;
    total;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field to be used for grouping purposes:

```
// {@grouper}
Ceiling(RecordNumber/3)
```

Add a group on this field.

Create a manual, running-total field:

```
// {@reset}
// place in group header; suppress

WhilePrintingRecords;
Stringvar Array reset;
Stringvar Array values;
values := reset;

// {@increment}
// place in details; suppress

WhilePrintingRecords;
Stringvar Array values;

Redim Preserve values[Ubound(values)+1];
values[Ubound(values)] := {table.name_field};

// {@display}
// place in group footer

WhilePrintingRecords;
Stringvar Array values;
Join(values, ", ");
```